# Entity not found with Symfony 5.1

Tags: php, symfony, class, doctrine-orm, entity

I have an issue with an Entity.
The goal is to display a Form which the user can use to change his personal information like the `Email` or `password`. I created a form for that, but when I created the `/Edit` Route I get the following error:

> "App\Entity\Users object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation."

Here's my Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Users;
use App\Form\EditProfileType;
use App\Form\UsersType;
use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/users")
 */
class UsersController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="users_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('users/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="users_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Users $user): Response
    {
        return $this->render('users/show.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/edit", name="users_edit")
     */
    public function editProfile(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(EditProfileType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addflash('message', 'Profile mis à jour');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('users');
        }

        return $this->render('users/editprofile.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Here's the form:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EditProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('pseudo', TextType::class)
            ->add('Valider', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Users::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here's the Entity Users:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UsersRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class Users implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Commentaires::class, mappedBy="auteur", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $commentaires;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Notes::class, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $note;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $pseudo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->commentaires = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->note = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Commentaires[]
     */
    public function getCommentaires(): Collection
    {
        return $this->commentaires;
    }

    public function addCommentaire(Commentaires $commentaire): self
    {
        if (!$this->commentaires->contains($commentaire)) {
            $this->commentaires[] = $commentaire;
            $commentaire->setAuteur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCommentaire(Commentaires $commentaire): self
    {
        if ($this->commentaires->contains($commentaire)) {
            $this->commentaires->removeElement($commentaire);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($commentaire->getAuteur() === $this) {
                $commentaire->setAuteur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Notes[]
     */
    public function getNote(): Collection
    {
        return $this->note;
    }

    public function addNote(Notes $note): self
    {
        if (!$this->note->contains($note)) {
            $this->note[] = $note;
            $note->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeNote(Notes $note): self
    {
        if ($this->note->contains($note)) {
            $this->note->removeElement($note);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($note->getUser() === $this) {
                $note->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPseudo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pseudo;
    }

    public function setPseudo(string $pseudo): self
    {
        $this->pseudo = $pseudo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here's the View Editprofile.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'basefront.html.twig' %}

{% block title %} Profile de {{ app.user.pseudo }} {% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <h1 class="h1 text-center">Modification du profile de {{ app.user.pseudo }}</h1>

    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about the /users/{id} show method and not the /users/edit route?

Comment: Hi, Im talking about the /users/edit method

Comment: The code you posted does not show the editProfile method using $users at all.  It just works on the current user.  Hence my question.

Comment: I want it to work on the current user online yes, and the editProfile method is on the first paste ;)

Comment: The code I am looking at shows $users being injected into the show method, not the editProfile method.  Oh well.  Hopefully someone else understands.  And completely off-topic but change the name of your Users entity to User and save yourself a great deal of future confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order matters. especially when routing without requirements. you have the following routes (update: added prefix, thanks @Cerad!):

```
/users/     users_index
/users/{id} users_show
/users/edit users_edit
```

now, when you request the uri `/users/edit` the UrlMatcher will iterate over your routes to see if and which matches, stopping on the first match.

`/users/` obviously doesn't match
`/users/{id}` does match, since `{id}` is allowed to be any alpha-numeric string (+ few extra chars), and `edit` matches that, leading to the `users_show` route, on which the `User` object cannot be determined by the id "edit`. And thus, the error message appears. One way to fix this would be to add requirements to the route matching - assuming the id is numerical only:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", ..., requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 */
```

I also agree with @Cerad that `Users` is a very bad name for an entity. They're usually in singular form.

Comment: They actually have a /users prefix on the controller so their routes look like /users/id and /users/edit .  Pretty sure all they need to do is change the edit route to /users/edit/id and then add the Users typehint to the editProfile method.  But there is an obvious communication disconnect.  But yes, order does matter and they should either have a /users/show/id method or add a criteria.

Comment: you're right about the prefix, doesn't change my point though. modified the answer. I'm not sure I agree about the /users/{id}/edit though, since he only wants the user to modify themself.

Comment: Okay.  Now I see.  The error is coming from trying to load a user with an id of 'edit' because the show method is matched instead of the editProfile method.

Comment: Problem solved guys, The solution was to change the order of the methods, juste switched user_show with user_edit and it works perfectly, I also changed the name of the entity "Users" to "User". Thank you #Jakumi